# Is "back the hall" accepted usage?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

In response to the question "Where is she?", I've heard someone say, "She's back the hall." (Cf. "She's back there.") I understand the meaning to be something like "She's down the hall," "She's in the hall," or "She's in some room connected to the hall."

It seems that *back* is functioning as a preposition here, as it doesn't quite fit the adverb usage in its [entry at M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back).

Is this a common usage in the sense of being documented in a reliable reference work or documented as an idiom or variant outside normal usage? If so, what part of speech is *back*?

---

**Update**: I have found an analogous phrase -- "Back the Alley", a decor and gift store in Gettysburg, Pennsylvania ([Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Back-the-Alley/166844700004128)). The proprietor told me the origin of the name: "We started out in an unnamed alley and told everyone to go back the alley to find us."

I have some Pennsylvania parentage, so that may be why this construction sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: what did the person mean when they said "She's back the hall"?

Comment: Most likely "back" functions as an adverb here as well, and in this particular example the speaker omitted the preposition "to" - "She's back [to] the hall".

Comment: Clarified question.

Comment: Given that we still have no idea where she is, other than somewhere in some way related to a hall, I'd be surprised if this is normal usage.  I'm sure it isn't in British English

Comment: Agreed, it could be anything OP enumerated, and some other things ("She's [in the] back [of] the hall"...). So yes, all we have is that this person is somewhere near the hall.

Comment: @PhilMJones I don't think the ambiguity of the meaning (where is she precisely?) is a problem. Someone "down the hall" might similarly be in the hall or a room connected to the hall, right? The phrase seems to me to be analogous to (if not a near equivalent of) "down the hall." I guess my question is that, because it sounds odd (to some ears at least) and doesn't fit any usage descriptions I've come across, is it an idiosyncratic (some would say, incorrect) usage or a documented/accepted usage, even if relatively rare. If the latter, is *back* functioning as a preposition like *down*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got a satisfactory answer from [an episode of "A Way with Words"](http://www.waywordradio.org/going-over-vs-going-over-to/). In short, this appears a case of locative prepositional deletion where "back" is still functioning as an adverb but the preposition (which could be, e.g., "in", "down", or "through") is omitted. Like the instance AWWW discussed, this appears to be a regional variant located in and around the great state of Pennsylvania (see updated details in the question).

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't grammatical English. Similar correct sentences would be "She's in the back of the hall" or "She's back in the hall" (note that these have different meanings). As you point out, it looks like the speaker was trying to use back as a preposition, but it can only be used as an adverb or noun.

Answer (score 2):

I non-ironically say "back the hall."  I grew up in Jasper, Indiana, and my grandparents and oldest aunts were native German speakers, but my mom doesn't remember how to speak German since they switched to speaking English at home when my aunt was in kindergarten.  Nevertheless, I often wonder if there is some relic of German grammar at play in this prepositional phrase in English.

By the way, I am often told that I have a standard Midwestern accent or "no accent."  A pronunciation quiz once told me I sound like I am from one of the Chicago suburbs, such as Naperville, Aurora, or Joliet, despite living 5 hours away from Chicago in the Hoosier apex of Southern twang.

Anyway, to say my mom is "back the hall" means she is in a room at the end of or down the hall whereas I am in the front of the house.  I don't necessarily know which bedroom or bathroom she went into.  She could even be admiring herself in the mirror at the end of the hall. I would only say this if I was in one of the rooms in the front of the house, such as the dining room, the living room, or the kitchen, not if I was in one of the bedrooms or bathrooms or the hall myself.  If I asked my mom where my clean socks were and she had already folded the laundry and put it away, she could also say I took it back the hall.  Back is contrastive in this context and functioning as a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

While I would agree that this is not correct English I would question the way in which it was said.  The origin of the speaker may well have influenced what was said.  By adding an apostrophe it becomes "She's back 'the hall" suggesting either "in" of "of" have been omitted which would be perfectly acceptable for someone from, for example, the Yorkshire region of England.